# How to identify why Chrome Browser takes 100% CPU (1 core) in Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

The Chrome's Task Manager shows the CPU is attributed to the *Browser* task.

I tried to run `spindump` and `sample process` from Activity Monitor, but they are way too complex to make any conclusions.

Is there any other way?

Comment: What does it say in Activity Monitor? The percentage value in there is **per core* not the overall CPU usage.

Comment: @Tetsujin It fluctuates around 100%. Yes, it's per core, but still very annoying.